# How to response array divided like using offset/limit in sequelize

Tags: node.js

I would like to response 9 arrays like using offset/limit in sequelize.
That is what I implemented in controller. I am taking data from sequelize in repository.

```
//controller    
getRobby = async (req, res, next) => {
      let pageNum = req.query.page;
      let offset = 0;

      if (pageNum > 1) {
        offset = 9 * (pageNum - 1);
      }
      const roomsInfo = await this.roomService.getRoomsInfo(offset);

      return res.json({ roomsInfo });
    
//repository
    const roomsInfo = await Rooms.findAll({
          offset: offset,
          limit: 9,
```

And I would like to send data like that. But the data what I need to send is one array using datas from the two tables. So I want to divide that "searchRoom" list.
I have been thinking using "for", but is it possible to send 9 datas whenever change the number of pages?

```
searchRoom = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      let pageNum = req.query.page;
      let offset = 0;

      if (pageNum > 1) {
        offset = 9 * (pageNum - 1);
      }
      const keyword = req.query;
      const searchRoom = await this.roomService.searchRoom(keyword);
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, searchRoom });
    } catch (err) {
      err.status, err.massage;
      next(err);
```